# How to model a list of free form text associated to a document in Skyve?

Tags: skyve

I have a Skyve document and I want to allow the user to add a list of free form text items.

e.g

- 5m of electrical cables
- T junction
- 5m conduit

is there a better way to model this than to have a new document with just a single text field?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually it makes sense to model lists as a new document as it will allow for the most flexible querying in subsequent functionality.

We have implemented use cases where we scatter and gather list contents into a memo field as comma separated values (CSV).

Skyve does not support this out of the box although we have planned to.

One way to implement this is to use an inline data grid bound to a non-persistent collection (maybe of admin.Generic) and perform the CSV transformations to a persistent memo field in the Document's Bizlet or in View Actions depending on the user interface requirements.
Keep in mind that a memo field is textually indexed by default, so it might be useful to turn that off for this use case.